# Extracting multiple rar files

Tags: winrar

I need to extract over 700 text files, is there a way you can extract the multiple files into one combined text file. They all have the same format so that is not an issue.

Comment: You're not going to be able to use WinRar to extract straight from the archive into a combined file unless the text files were originally part of one file that was split into multiple RAR files.  If you have the 700 text files already extracted, you can use the command prompt to copy them all to a single file ([several methods suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12342764/933524))

Comment: Yes, this is a two-step problem. 1) extract the files. Most extractors handle multiple files just fine. 2) merge the extracted files.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with console version `Rar.exe` to extract all text files in a RAR archive file into one text file. The command line to use is:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" p -inul "Text Files Archive.rar" >"Single File.txt"
```

The manual for console version of *WinRAR* is the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* which describes command `p` used with switch `-inul`. `Rar.exe` supports only RAR archives. Other archive file types are supported only by `WinRAR.exe`. So this command line cannot be used for extracting all text files in a ZIP file into one text file.

This command line prints the content of all files inside the RAR archive file to handle **stdout** and Windows command processor `cmd.exe` redirects the output into the single text file.

The command line above works by default for OEM, ANSI and UTF-8 encoded text files inside the RAR archive file. All text files inside RAR archive should have same [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).